# Import data from textfile containing comment lines and lines to skip before data

Tags: r, csv, read.table

I tried to import the [UV/VIS spectrum of Acetone published in the NIST webbook](https://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/cbook.cgi?JCAMP=C67641&Index=0&Type=UVVis). Despite of being named a `jdx` file, this is rather a text file containing some meta data as comments and the comma-separated spectrum data.

If you have a closer look into the file (simply open it with a text editor), the comment lines start with a `##`. However, lines 6 & 7 do contain meta data which does not need to be imported and is not marked as a comment. Therefore I need to skip these two lines. The comma-separated spectrum data starts in line 35 and is closed with another comment `##END=`.

Using R's `read.table()` function, I tried to import the data as follows:

```
acetone.spectrum <- read.table(file="./67-64-1-UVVis.jdx", comment.char="#", sep=",", header=FALSE, skip=2)
```

This line raises an error:

```
Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : 
  line 1 did not have 2 elements
```

What am I missing here?